# Using Ada with C#

Tags: c#, ada

Is there any way we can run Ada programming language code managed by C#?

Something simple like this:

```
int x = 10, y = 20;
int anwser = (int)runAdaFunction('add',x,y);
```

Thanks for all the anwsers :)

Comment: There is A# / Ada.net.  You should be able to compile that to IL and call it from C#.

Comment: Do you have a dll for the Ada? You should be able to run any dll from a c# project.

Comment: "run Ada programming language code managed by C#" is totally unclear and germinologically, eh, bizzare. Describe the problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile an Ada library to a DLL.  The details are explained in the documentation for GCC/GNAT.